# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ,FOREIGN KEY (`doctorid`) REFERENCES `doctors` (`doctorid`) in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Here I'm trying to add data to tourplan table using Spring JPA with entities and controllers and it's giving the #Error:
`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (healthcare_api.tourplan, CONSTRAINT FK15trnihq1v099oq9ygi7uqv1l FOREIGN KEY (doctorid) REFERENCES doctors (doctorid))`

**Tourplan.java:**:

```java
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long tourid ;
                private int eid;
                private int approved = 0;
                private String status = "pending";private String name, gender, 
                address, clinicphone;
                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @JoinColumn(name="doctorid")
                private  Doctor doctors;
        
                 public void setDoctorId(long doctorid) {
                      doctors.setDoctorid(doctorid);
                 }
//getter and setter
```

**Doctor.java:**

```java
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private long doctorid;
            
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="doctors",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            private Collection<Tourplan> tplans;
```

**TourplanController.java**:

```java
    @PostMapping("/tourplan/add")
    public String addTourPlan(@RequestBody Tourplan tourplan) 
    {
        tourplanRepository.save(tourplan);
        return "Tourplan Added";
    }
```

Comment: You should try to remove the `doctorid` field from the `Tourplan` entity. What the purpose of mapping it twice (`private int doctorid` and  `private Doctor doctors`)?

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi FOREIGN KEY error is fixed but setter method for doctorid is giving following Error : # Column 'doctorid' cannot be null

Comment: You should set `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` and set two-side entities relations. Look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081753/spring-data-jpa-how-do-i-save-an-item-with-multiple-child-collections/65089159#65089159

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi I have add cascade=CascadeType.ALL in OneToMany Relationship but it gives the same error: #Column 'doctorid' cannot be null

Comment: can you show the `tourplan` you save?

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi I have updated the tourplan please check it.

Comment: I mean an object (json) you get as argument of the controller method `addTourPlan`. I cant understand the sense of `doctorId` entity field. The field setter looks weird

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi my problem is I have using controller addTourPlan save the tourplan but I was used in doctor and tourplan table in the mapping , my all data display using GetMapping getTourPlan controller but not add/save the tourplan with the help of PostMapping